# Exchange sort number of comparisons and exchanges

Tags: c++

I just have a simple question for the day, I have been looking online for some sort of formula that calculates the number of comparisons and exchanges for exchange sort. I know for selection sort the average number of comparisons would be n(n-1)/2

Comment: What is your question to ask here?

Comment: How to calculate number of comparisons for an exchange sort algorithm

Comment: That's easy: every time an exchange is made, increment a counter. Problem solved. Next question, please.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik so if had 10 elements in an array. I would use 10(10-1)?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I think he means calculate it before the fact.

Comment: Yes @Carcigenicate I'm doing a analysis

Comment: Just look up the time complexity of a exchange sort. I'm sure Wikipedia says it.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I looked, surprisingly they don't have it for this algorithm.

Comment: @Thompson "Exchange sort" isn't an umbrella term meaning several different sorts is it?

Comment: @Carcigenicate I think its similar to bubble sort. but this is one sorts it differently

Comment: @Thompson You might just need to analyze the algorithm to figure it out.

Comment: Bottom of https://www.macs.hw.ac.uk/~pjbk/pathways/cpp2/node68.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this page](https://www.macs.hw.ac.uk/~pjbk/pathways/cpp2/node68.html), exchange sort has a time complexity of `O(n^2)`.